# Mousewheel detect not work in webview pyside2

Tags: python, pyside2, mousewheel

I want to get mousewheel value delta. With  WHeelEvent(self,event) function but is don't work when the webview is focus

I try  it with other layout widgets and is work correctly

How i can do for get it in my webview please ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

QWebEngineView uses the focusProxy to handle mouse events so you should listen for events from that widget using an eventfilter:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QEvent, QUrl
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class WebView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # required for the focusProxy to be created
        self.load(QUrl())
        self.focusProxy().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.focusProxy() and event.type() == QEvent.Type.Wheel:
            print(event.angleDelta())
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


def main():
    app = QApplication()

    w = WebView()
    w.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/"))
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```